# How to initialize std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Class>> - cannot compile

Tags: c++

I have a class, Projectile. From another class `Tower`, I am trying to store a vector of `unique_ptrs` to this class, Projectile.

This is how I am initializing the list in my header file:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Projectile>> projectiles;
```

However, I get this error when I try to compile the program:

```
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/vector:63,
                 from C:\Users\charl\Documents\Code\C C++\Bloons/main.cpp:4:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool std::__check_constructible() [with _ValueType = unique_ptr<Projectile>; _Tp = const unique_ptr<Projectile>&]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:182:4:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unique_ptr<Projectile>*, vector<unique_ptr<Projectile> > >; _ForwardIterator = unique_ptr<Projectile>*]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:372:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unique_ptr<Projectile>*, vector<unique_ptr<Projectile> > >; _ForwardIterator = unique_ptr<Projectile>*; _Tp = unique_ptr<Projectile>]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:601:31:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Projectile>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Projectile> >]'
C:\Users\charl\Documents\Code\C C++\Bloons/tower.hpp:15:7:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
   90 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType, _Tp>::value,
```

I have removed any code adding to or indexing the vector, so it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Projectile needs a default constructor

Comment: Note that what the compiler needs and what you need may not be the same thing. Before you add that default constructor, make sure that the default constructor is required to do something you actually want done.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I agree with pm100, this is most likely the result of lacking a default constructor. It should be noted that, when making any class in C++, to always include the big 3: default constructor, copy constructor, and destructor. The first ensures all instances will be instantiated, the second ensures that you can always pass by value, and the third ensures no memory leaks will occur. While these aren't always a necessity, including them can help minimize unexpected behavior. If you create a default constructor and you're still running into this issue, please update your post accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: *"I have removed any code adding to or indexing the vector, so it has nothing to do with that."* -- good start. How much more code can you remove? Or maybe in this case it would be easier to build up a [mre] from scratch? You could try starting with `#include <memory> #include <vector> class Projectile {}; int main() { std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Projectile>> projectiles; }` then add pieces until the error re-appears. Well, since `Projectile` is the non-standard part, maybe start by adding its full definition and (if the error reappears) working backwards from that.

Answer (score 0):

From this line of compiler error:

```
error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
```

The class `Projectile` needs a default constructor. Add one.

```cpp
class Projectile {
public:
    Projectile() = default;
};
```

---

From c++11, [rule-of-five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is implemented when it comes to managing resources:

```cpp
class Projectile {
    int member {};

public:
    Projectile() = default; // Default c'tor
    Projectile(const Projectile&) = default; // Copy c'tor
    Projectile(Projectile&&) noexcept = default; // Move c'tor
    Projectile& operator=(const Projectile&) = default; // Copy assignment
    Projectile& operator=(Projectile&&) noexcept = default; // Move assignment
    ~Projectile() noexcept = default; // Default d'tor
};
```